# retrieve PID of an unrelated android app

Tags: android, android-activity

**I want to run an app which reports the PID of a completely different app (lets say the gmail app for example)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName());
private Map<Integer, String> pidMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses)
    {
        pidMap.put(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
        logger.info("pid: " + runningAppProcessInfo.pid + " | " + runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
    }
}
```

}

**Log output:**
pid: 31052 | com.example.user508771.pidSniffer

The problem is I don't care about the PID of the app running this... I want the PID of the gmail app which is not a process or subprocess of my app. Every answer related to this keeps telling me to use activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses() which seems to not do what I need it to do. Do I need to root my phone and use a lower level API and NDK?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the PID?

Comment: I want to write a c++ app which runs on a rooted android which takes the pid and can read memory addresses set beythe process with a given pid.